# Skycons, cant display the same icon twice?

Tags: javascript, css

I've hooked up the JavaScript plugin "Skycons" to Yahoo weather RSS feed. The problem I am having is that multiple days may have the same weather forecast and because the plugin pulls the icons from  ID instead of  class I am unable to pull the same icon a second time.

For example, all icons below will show apart from the last li instance - because I have repeated the id snow:

```
<ul class="days">
       <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><strong>Saturday</strong>
             <canvas id="snow" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
             <span>19&deg;</span>
       </li>
       <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><strong>Sunday</strong>
             <canvas id="rain" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
             <span>19&deg;</span>
       </li>
       <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><strong>Monday</strong>
             <canvas id="sleet" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
             <span>19&deg;</span>
       </li>
       <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><strong>Wednesday</strong>
             <canvas id="snow" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
             <span>19&deg;</span>
       </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my init JS:

```
<!--SkyCons-->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendors/skycons/skycons.js"></script> 
<script>
      var icons = new Skycons({"color": "#fff"}),
          list  = [
            "clear-day", "clear-night", "partly-cloudy-day",
            "partly-cloudy-night", "cloudy", "rain", "sleet", "snow", "wind",
            "fog"
          ],
          i;

      for(i = list.length; i--; )
        icons.set(list[i], list[i]);

      icons.play();
    </script>
```

and here is a link to the referenced JS file:

https://github.com/darkskyapp/skycons/blob/master/skycons.js

Comment: What is the script you run to initialize the plugin ?

Comment: Please see above, I have edited the original post to include this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the version that works with element references instead of `id`

(*And change the html to use classes instead of ids*)

```
for(i = list.length; i--; ) {
    var weatherType = list[i],
        elements = document.getElementsByClassName( weatherType );
    for (e = elements.length; e--;){
        icons.set( elements[e], weatherType );
    }
}
```

and change your html to

```
   <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><strong>Saturday</strong>
         <canvas class="snow" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
         <span>19&deg;</span>
   </li>
   <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><strong>Sunday</strong>
         <canvas class="rain" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
         <span>19&deg;</span>
   </li>
   <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><strong>Monday</strong>
         <canvas class="sleet" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
         <span>19&deg;</span>
   </li>
   <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><strong>Wednesday</strong>
         <canvas class="snow" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
         <span>19&deg;</span>
   </li>
```

If you need to support IE8 and older you need to use this polyfill for the `getElementsByClassName` function: [Polyfill for getElementsByClassName for particular uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944659/polyfill-for-getelementsbyclassname-for-particular-uses)

Comment: Spot on, works perfectly thank you. It won't let me mark answer as useful as reputation below 15.

Comment: @TomHughes you can accept it as the correct with the checkmark under the voting buttons, if you want.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli this definitely helped me out. Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/damiththa/pen/xOOEZQ?editors=1010)