# ReferenceError: e is not defined in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im having a problem with my react app, where im unable to show the same icon from [skycons](https://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/) twice.
I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572100/skycons-cant-display-the-same-icon-twice) with the same issue. However - when I copy the solution I get an error `bundle.js:130 Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`

For reference this is my code

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
  this.setState({
    forecast: result.currently,
    daily: result.daily.data
  });
  var icons = new Skycons({
      "color": "#666"
    }),
    list = [
      "clear-day", "clear-night", "partly-cloudy-day",
      "partly-cloudy-night", "cloudy", "rain", "sleet", "snow", "wind",
      "fog"
    ],
    i;

  for (i = list.length; i--;) {
    var weatherType = list[i],
      elements = document.getElementsByClassName(weatherType);
    for (e = elements.length; e--;) {
      icons.set(elements[e], weatherType);
    }
  }

  icons.play();
 }.bind(this));
}
```

I've tried to declare `e` different places in the code, but it didn't work for me, even though the code is copy/pasted

And *obviously* the error is somewhere here `for (e = elements.length; e--;) {`

Comment: Where is e defined? `var e;`

Comment: Nowhere. Its not defines in the code from the other post, and i cant seem to figure out where i should declare it

Comment: before you use it...

Comment: Been there, done that. Same error

Comment: so `elements = document.getElementsByClassName(weatherType), e;` fails?

Comment: That works mate. I've declared it like three or four other places, but i didn't try there. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126544/discussion-between-c-poulsen-and-epascarello).

Comment: I try to stay away from trying to directly access the dom in react. It may be a bit naive of me, but I try to trust the refs that react provides on top of the virtual dom.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
  for (i = list.length; i--;) {
    var weatherType = list[i],
      elements = document.getElementsByClassName(weatherType);
    for (var e = elements.length; e > 0; e--) {
      icons.set(elements[e], weatherType);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This just returns a console error from the skycons.js script

Comment: The biggest difference I can see here is that you should have a delimiter. e > 0 which should prevent from running for eternity. But should also include i > 0.