# Can I add method to a custom class of an HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, class

My question is similar to this:

[How to add my own methods to HTMLElement object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670361/how-to-add-my-own-methods-to-htmlelement-object)

Since the answer is 'NO', I'm wondering if I can add a method to the class instead of the HTMLElement itself, like:

```
<SELECT class="sel_region">

<script>
$(function(){

  $('.sel_region').doSomething();

});
</script>
```

If possible, how to achieve it?

Comment: how would you invoke this function?

Comment: This is how I invoke it:
    
    $('.sel_region').doSomething();

Just don't know how to define it.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.sel_region')` isn't a class. Assuming you're using jQuery, it's a collection of all the elements on the page that have the `sel_region` class. If you would like to be able to add a method to jQuery, this is the link for you:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

You could do something like:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  doSomething: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      // Do something to the matching elements, which will be `this`
   });
});

$('.one-class').doSomething();
$('.another-class').doSomething();
```

Comment: @abacusit You're welcome. If you're satisfied with this answer click the tick next to it to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You, of course, could do this. You should loop all existing htmlElement instances with current class

```
$(".sel_region").each(function(index, element) {
  element.prototype.yourFunction = function() { console.log("exists!"); };
});
```

You should call this loop on Dom load