# Rebuild jQuery native functions to HTMLElements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reimplement the jQuery functions.

For example [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

I found some threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670361/how-to-add-my-own-methods-to-htmlelement-object).

So I tried something like:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.attr = (pAttributeName, pAttributeValue) => {
  if(pAttributeValue){
    this.setAttribute(pAttributeName, pAttributeValue);
  } else {
      return this.getAttribute(pAttributeName);
  }
};
```

**But it don't work. Do I have to init the Elements first, in a constructor?**

Comment: What "didn't work" about it? Did you check the error console?

Comment: Yes, there isn't anything, but @User863 had the answer! :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable)

Comment: Not realy, because there a different questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a
> shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds
> the this value

In your case, `this` was bound to `window` object.

**Using regular function**

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.attr = function(pAttributeName, pAttributeValue) {
  if (pAttributeValue) {
    this.setAttribute(pAttributeName, pAttributeValue);
  } else {
    return this.getAttribute(pAttributeName);
  }
};

document.querySelector('h1').attr('id', 'head')
```

```css
#head {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for your pretty cool answer! Really appreciate it!