# Give function parameter before itself

Tags: javascript, function

Is it possible calling element in function if I write that element before the function,
example:

```js
let demo = document.getElementById("demo")
demo.giveMeElement()

function demo() {
  // How can I get that #demo element here
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4670387/9074272) answers your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add my own methods to HTMLElement object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670361/how-to-add-my-own-methods-to-htmlelement-object)

Comment: While it is possible. You are using the same name for both. Choose a different name for your element and use it inside the function.

Comment: `HTMLElement.prototype.doHello = function(thing){
    alert('Hello World from ' + thing);
  };
header_img.doHello();` - it doesn't really work...

Comment: Yes, of course, As I understand your question, `demo` is a global variable for the function `demo`. So you can access `#demo` element through `demo` variable and do whatever the operations which are allowed with it. @TusharShahi suggestion is also should be considered.